# Switching view controllers from UIToolbar subclass

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Please excuse my newness in IOS, but I am trying to switch view controllers when someone clicks on a button in my toolbar. For my toolbar I have overridden the UIToolbar and drawn my own custom toolbar. I have four buttons each with their own action something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [@[] mutableCopy];
[toolbarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notifications"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(viewNotifications)]];
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
-(void)viewNotifications
{
    NSLog(@"CustomUIToolbar::viewNotifications");

    //layoutFlow....

    // Show the notifications view controller
    NotificationsViewController *rootViewController = [[NotificationsViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:layoutFlow];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

The problem with this is clearly that the UIToolbar doesn't directly have access to switching view controllers. Is there a way to access the presentViewController method or something like it from within the custom UIToolbar?

Comment: Not related to the issue: `[@[] mutableCopy]` should probably be `[NSMutableArray array]` (more readable, and prevent allocating a NSArray).

Comment: Thanks for the tip Algis I'll make the change!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a protocol and a delegate and let the `UIViewController` which creates the `UIToolBar` implement that delegate.

When the user presses a `UIBarButtonItem` you send the delegate the message (the main `UIViewController`) and handle the `UINavigationController` code there.

```
@protocol ToolBarProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)didPressButton1;

@end

@property (nonatomic) id <ToolBarProtocol> delegate
```

And when creating your `UIToolBar`:

```
YourToolBar *toolbar = [YourToolBar alloc] init];
toolbar.delegate = self;
```

Inside your method change to tell the delegate what should happen:

```
-(void)viewNotifications
{
    NSLog(@"CustomUIToolbar::viewNotifications");

    //layoutFlow....
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didPressButton1)])
    {
        [self.delegate didPressButton1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Delegate's are one of the most used/powerful iOS patterns, try to use them whenever you can. They're easy to maintain, and easy to extend